# League of legends fullscreen

Tags: 14.04

I have League of Legens running in full screen, when I want to switch to another app, I can't, Leage of Legens stays in full screen on top,

Comment: Jajajaja, aún con el mismo problema?. Intente con Wine 1.9.19-Staging. Puede también, desde la configuración de Wine, habilitar la opción de Emular escritorio. Actualize la versión de Ubuntu, o use Xubuntu y deshabilite el compositor desde los ajustes. A mí me cambia entre pantallas perfectamente en XFCE, aún con el compositor habilitado.